# Apple iPod 30pin to micro usb

Tags: usb, ipod

Not sure if this is off topic. I have an old ipod dock with a 30 pin male connect and I want to switch it out to a male micro usb. So that I can use the dock. I don't want to use an adapter as I want it to look natural.

I was simply going to rewire old connector to the micro usb.

Ipod Dock pinouts
I have found the pinouts for both. 
http://pinouts.ru/PortableDevices/ipod_pinout.shtml

Micro usb.

http://pinouts.ru/PortableDevices/mini-USB_pinout.shtml

It looks like I can simply connect up the 16, 23, 25 and 27 on the ipod connector to 4, 3,2,1 respectively on the micro usb side.

Just wanna make sure before I do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, since it's USB which is standard protocol.

But you can't use speaker because dock's speaker is connected to pin 3 & 4.

If you want to use it, you can solder an audio cable to pin 2, 3 & 4.

Comment: It really sucks that you can not use the pins that are already there.